# How to call function from child component in parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-components

I have parent components

```
<div md-dialog-content>
  <div class="section-top">
    <p id="title" style="float:left;">Adding Dockument</p>
    <div md-dialog-actions style="float:right;">
      <button class="edm-button inline" md-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">Cancel</button>
      <button class="edm-button inline" md-button (click)="onClick()" tabindex="-1">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <app-document-data [buttonMessage]="buttonMessage"></app-document-data>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Child component  i have method
onSubmit() { }

I have a question when to call onSubmit() function when i click a button confirm in parrent component.

I know that i probably should use @Input and @Output decorator but i don't know how properly.

Comment: Is onSubmit method belong to app-document-data component?

Comment: @Faly, yes onSubmit method belong to app-document-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's even easier : give your child a template reference, and you can call its functions like so : *(I guess your second button will make the call)*

```
<div md-dialog-content>
  <div class="section-top">
    <p id="title" style="float:left;">Adding Dockument</p>
    <div md-dialog-actions style="float:right;">
      <button class="edm-button inline" md-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">Cancel</button>
      <button class="edm-button inline" md-button (click)="appDD.onSubmit()" tabindex="-1">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <app-document-data #appDD [buttonMessage]="buttonMessage"></app-document-data>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is more a suggestion not an answer to his question can be posted as a comment.

Comment: Well, try it yourslef and post the code in a comment !

Comment: Seems to not work for me.
**Cannot read property 'save' of undefined**
`<edit-order #editOrderRef></edit-order>`
`<button class="button-success" (click)="editOrderRef.save()">Save</button>`

Answer (score 1):

In your parent component:

```
onClick(){
  this.buttonMessage = true;
```

In your child:

```
@Input() buttonMessage: boolean;
```

And a ngOnChanges:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
  if(changes.buttonMessage.currentValue){
     this.onSubmit();
```

Comment: Swoox it's works fine, ngOnchanges() execute only one, but i need that method execute more that one i try in ngOnChanges set buttonMessage = false and now use @Output to send data to parent

Comment: This is cause you need to change the value to false again. ngOnChanges work on change not if **buttonMessage.currentValue === true** and **buttonMessage.previousValue === true** . It need to be **buttonMessage.previousValue === false**. *Sorry for the late reply*

Comment: i find 
simpler way only using local reference <app-document-data #DocumentDataComponent></app-document-data>                                                     <button class="edm-button inline" md-button (click)="DocumentDataComponent.onSubmit()" tabindex="-1">Zatwierdź</button>